# qooxdoo : Image Button remove padding border?

Tags: qooxdoo

I have an image button which looks like :

[image: my image button]

Here is my code for the image button :

```
var button = new qx.ui.form.Button(null, "myapp/test.png");
container.add(button, { left: 10, top: 10 });
```

How to remove the button border & the padding ? I want to display the image only.

note: `container` is a `qx.ui.layout.Canvas`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The border and padding are defined by the button's decorator, which is nullable:

```
button.setDecorator(null);
```

Comment: works perfect ! By the way, I'm proposing a new StackExchange for qooxdoo: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/54797/qooxdoo